# Find the current stdout OR How to redirect the output back to console

Tags: ruby, linux, terminal, subprocess

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 x64 and,

I have a file *startup.rb* in which I call *sudo bash*, so that I always have a root console to do administrative tasks without typing password after every 15 minutes or so.

This script is called by another script *Startup.rb*, and content of both files are like this -

File *~/Startup.rb*

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
system "gnome-terminal --maximize -x ruby ~/startup.rb"
```

File *~/startup.rb*

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
`sudo some-repetitive-administrative-task`
....
....
`sudo bash` #Not using `sudo -i`, since that makes `pwd` -> /root
```

I have included the *~/Startup.rb* file in *Startup Applications* list.

Now the problem is that, in the terminal of `sudo bash`, if I type something and expect some output, I don't get any. So if I write `echo hello world`, I don't get any output. Which leads me to believe that the standard output (stdout) of the `sudo bash` command is *not* the console.

So, I want to know why is this happening? How may I know the current stdout path? Or how can I restore stdout back to my current console?

-- thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an inapproriate method to run system commands from Ruby.  Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

system 'bash'
```

The syntax you're using (with the backticks) captures the standard output of the command and returns it in a string.  That's why you don't see it on the terminal.

Here's a nice review of the different ways to run commands from Ruby: [6 Ways to Run Shell Commands in Ruby](http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/03/ruby-shell-commands.html).

Comment: Well that's frustrating, because I always used system("") until recently when I discovered ``.
I tried almost all ways I could, and did I just missed trying system()?
Even in the same file `startup.rb`, every other command is executed using system() except this one as I had added this line recently.
That's insane.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in an easier way to run administrative tasks as root, there might be a few other things you might consider.

```
$sudo -s
```

This will give you a shell in which you can submit commands as your sudo'd self (assuming that sudo has been setup so that you can run a shell via sudo).

Another thing you can do, though not always recommended or considered good form in Ubuntu is to [create a root account](http://www.debianadmin.com/enable-and-disable-ubuntu-root-password.html):

```
$sudo passwd root
```

then you can login as root and administer things that way.

I know this doesn't answer your specific question about ruby, but I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'd prefer `sudo -s` over `sudo bash` now.